# azure piplines resources template from other github repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to create a central point repository with templates for all my rust projects. And in other projects I just wanna add link to them:

here is an example link to my templates repository. You can find them [here](https://github.com/xoac/rust-azure-pipelines/tree/c1e4f00ed8224ed80a8d66e33c17c2d85a188784).

```
trigger: ["master"]
pr: ["master"]

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: github
      name: xoac/rust-azure-pipelines

# Test top level crate
- template: azure-test-stable.yml@templates
  parameters:
    name: test_tokio
    displayName: Test tokio
    cross: true
```

And I am getting an error [here](https://dev.azure.com/sylwesterrapala/tokio-fs-stream/_build/results?buildId=17&view=results)
[image: Error when using templates from other resources]

I have found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#repository-resource) that I need specify service connection.

> If you choose github as your type, then name is the full name of the GitHub repo including the user or organization. For example, Microsoft/vscode. Also, GitHub repos require a [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops) for authorization.

---

- I don't know what type of connection this should be.
- I want to make it accessible to everyone who want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It would be a `Github` service connection (when you create new service connection)
2. Permissions are granted on build level, not on user level, so anyone who can launch the build would be able to launch it and it would work
3. for github repo name, i think you are using the correct one, but you would also need to add `endpoint: service_connection_name` to the repositories definition.

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#repository-resource